# Paperclip not working under Apache/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip, passenger, phusion

I've deployed my rails application on a staging/production machine running Apache and Phusion Passenger but cannot get the Paperclip gem to load correctly (or at least to get the piece of the application working that uses it). Other gems seem to load fine and when I set `config.cache_classes` to `false` in the RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/staging.rb the rest of the application works fine. If it is set to true I get the following Passenger message in the browser (and apache error log) and cannot use the application at all:

```
Error message:
undefined method `validates_attachment_presence' for #<Class:0xb618e938>

Exception class:
NoMethodError
```

I've googled around for quite some time but cannot find a solution for this issue I am having. I hope I am not overlooking something obvious...

UPDATE 21/8: On the same box running the rails app with sudo script/server -b 17x.7x.16x.3x -e staging works fine. Could this be a permission problem and Passenger not being able to find the installed Paperclip Gem?

Hope you can give me some pointers, let me know if you need more info! Thanks Mark

Some information on my environment:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
```

RAILS_ROOT/config/environment.rb has this set:

```
config.gem "paperclip", :version => "~> 2.3"
```

Gems environment:

```
   $ gem env
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
      - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86-linux
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /var/lib/gems/1.8
         - /home/mark/.gem/ruby/1.8
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :benchmark => false
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Gems list on the server:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.0.9, 2.3.5)
activemodel (3.0.9)
activerecord (3.0.9, 2.3.5)
activeresource (3.0.9, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.9, 2.3.5)
arel (2.1.3, 2.0.10)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
capistrano (2.6.0)
cocaine (0.1.0)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
highline (1.6.2)
i18n (0.4.2)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql (2.8.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
paperclip (2.3.12)
passenger (3.0.7)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.3, 1.1.0, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
```

Paperclip gem is installed here:

```
$ sudo find / -name 'paperclip'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/doc/paperclip-2.3.12/rdoc/files/lib/paperclip
/var/lib/gems/1.8/doc/paperclip-2.3.12/rdoc/files/lib/generators/paperclip
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.12/lib/paperclip
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.12/lib/generators/paperclip
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.12/generators/paperclip
```

Apache virtualhost config:

```
$ more /etc/apache2/sites-available/staging.mydomain.com 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName staging.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /u/apps/mydomain.com/current/public
    RailsEnv staging 
</VirtualHost>
```

Some additional stack trace from the passenger page (btw: tried removing the will_paginate plugin, but the result is exactly the same; it throws an error at active_record/base.rb):

```
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb 1959    in `method_missing_without_paginate'
1   /u/apps/mydomain.com/releases/20110705192718/vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb   170 in `method_missing'
2   /u/apps/mydomain.com/releases/20110705192718/app/models/image.rb    5   
3   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
5   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   158 in `require'
6   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   265 in `require_or_load'
7   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   224 in `depend_on'
8   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb   136 in `require_dependency'
9   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb   414 in `load_application_classes'
10  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb   413 in `each'
```

Code for the image class:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validate_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_uniqueness_of :photo_file_name, :scope => :user_id

  has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/assets/:user/app/:class/:style_:basename.:
extension", 
    :path => "#{APP_PATH}/:user/app/:class/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "50x50#",
      :large =>   "400x" }
end
```

config/environment.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
  config.active_record.observers = :user_observer #, :website_observer
  config.gem "paperclip", :version => "~> 2.3"
end

SITE_NAME = 'Mydomain.com'
CMS_PREFIX = 'joomla'
```

config/environments.rb/staging.rb

```
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

# The staging environment is meant for finished, apps and final acceptance testing.
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true
config.action_view.cache_template_loading            = true


ActionController::Base.asset_host = "staging.mydomain.com"

DOCUMENT_ROOT = "/var/www"
APP_PATH = "/u/apps"
DB_PREFIX = "a001"
DB_USER = "joomla" 
DB_PWD = "*****"
GIT_URL = "git@github.com:****/mydomain.git"

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,    
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => "587",
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "****@gmail.com",
    :password => "****"
  }
```

Comment: What does `gem list` show on the server?

Comment: added it in the original post.

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like the error is coming from line 5 of app/models/image.rb - can you post your model code here as well?

Comment: added code for app/models/image.rb

Comment: Did you figure out the cause of your problem? Was it related to an error in (or possible not having) the staging environment file?

Comment: UPDATE: On the same box running the rails app with sudo script/server -b 17x.7x.16x.3x -e staging works fine. Could this be a permission problem and Passenger not being able to find the installed Paperclip Gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've solved this by adding

```
require "paperclip"
```

to the image.rb class.

I am going with this workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `validate_attachment_presence` line after the `has_attached_file` block - `has_attached_file` includes Paperclip's instance methods so there could be a problem in the ordering. I know that class loading differs between dev and production environments, but I'm not sure of the extent of those differences.

Comment: Hi, good suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work, but it did change the error message: Error message:
undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0xb62aa808>
Exception class:
NoMethodError

Comment: So clearly, the Paperclip gem is not being loaded - what does your config/environments/staging.rb file look like?

Comment: added both config/environment.rb and config/environments/staging.rb to the original post.

Comment: I've also tried with config.gem "paperclip", :version => "~> 2.3" in the staging.rb but gives the same result...

Answer (score 0):

You mis-typed the validation method. According to the [Paperclip Rdoc](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Shoulda/Matchers%3avalidate_attachment_presence), the correct method name is `validate_attachment_presence` - it is "validate" not "validates".

Comment: Same issue: Error message:
undefined method `validate_attachment_presence' for #<Class:0xb6121770>
Exception class:
NoMethodError

Comment: Also bear in mind that this piece of code works fine on my developmnet machine.